# SharePoint: Execute query

Tags: csom, list-item

I have a misunderstanding with the command `ExecuteQuery();`

I have created a piece of code which read an array and copy its values in a list so here my piece of code:

```
foreach (var variable in mobjList)
{
   oListItem[variable.FieldNameTarget] = false;
   oListItem.Update();
}

lobjCtx.ExecuteQuery();
```

My code works but I don't understand why in my SharePoint list history, I have 15 lines (one line for each item),
I tried to add oListItem.Update() outside of my loop but I just get one item in my list after that

any idea if is it possible to get all events in one line?
Edit: here the piece of code I use:

```
    foreach (var variable in mobjProjectList)
    {
 if (variable.FieldUser == "Person")
       {
          User userTest = lobjCtx.Web.EnsureUser(variable.FieldValue);
          lobjCtx.Load(userTest);
         lobjCtx.ExecuteQuery();
          string name = userTest.Id.ToString() + ";#" + userTest.LoginName.ToString();
          oListItem[variable.FieldNameTarget] = name;
       
       }
       else if (variable.FieldUser == "Bool")
       {
          if (variable.FieldValue == "True")
          {
             oListItem[variable.FieldNameTarget] = true;
       
          }
          else
          {
             oListItem[variable.FieldNameTarget] = false;
        
          }

       }
       else
       {
          oListItem[variable.FieldNameTarget] = variable.FieldValue;

           }
   }
 oListItem.Update();
    lobjCtx.ExecuteQuery();
    return true;
```

The first piece of code, if it's a person I convert it to be able to get a person in my target list
if it's a bool I convert it to true and if it's a line of text I just copy it

[image]
Thank you for your feedback

As you can see, many items are created by the programm:

Comment: any specific reason to have all the events in single line?

Comment: Are you saying you have 15 columns and you want to fill values in these 15columns?

Comment: Yes, if I was able to get all items in a specific line, it will be easier to follow the change in my list

Answer (score 2):

Keep the update statement outside the loop and try to update. Refer code below.

```
foreach (var variable in mobjList)
{
   oListItem[variable.FieldNameTarget] = false;
}
oListItem.Update();
lobjCtx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I tried that but it didn't work, only the last item of my loop will be added in my list

Comment: Seems you are doing multiple items update.. share more code to see the scenario in detail.

Comment: Share the snapshot of your list as well.

Comment: I added my code in comment in my initial post 
Once again thank you for your help

Comment: What is mobjProjectList and where are you generating oListItem? Code is still not clear and what you are trying to implement and achieve.

Comment: mobjProjectList is just a class which contains 3 strings and 2 int
My olist item is generated by two ways, oListItem = oList.GetItemById(mstrUpdate) if the item already exists and if it's a new : oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

I'm getting some data from SQL and then I write these data in my sharePoint list everything works well, it's just SharePoint which would like to avoid to geta line for each field which is updated

Comment: Do you mean in version history it is showing you one line for each field updated?. If you update the screenshot, it will give us clear picture.

Comment: Once again thank you for your time
I edited my post, so I'd like to know if it's possible to have everything in only one line and not 9 like on the picture